# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'avatar')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.io

I'm new to stack overflow and I realize this question has already been asked but the answers didn't work and I wasn't sure what else to do. Anyways I'm new to programming and wanted to create a discord bot. I followed this tutorial https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/. The function is the same as in the tutorial, but I changed the command from ping and changed the response from pong. I got the bot to work fine, but when my friend tried inviting the bot to his server it completely stopped working on all servers. Here is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'avatar')
    at Member.set [as avatar] (C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:2622:48)
    at copyKeys (C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1542:11)
    at new Member (C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:2613:2)
    at C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:2559:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Server (C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:2557:15)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1891:31)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.onbinary (C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:848:10)
    at C:\Users\Jacob R\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:628:18
```

As I said I followed the answers on the old question but neither worked. Please help.

Comment: It would be easier to identify the problem if you share your code or code block where you wanted to set 'avatar'.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.